# I have a syntax error in my query builder

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony4

```
`$allConsultation = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Consultation::class);
    $spConsultation = $allConsultation->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->select('c')
                    ->addselect('user')
                    ->addselect('p')
                    ->leftJoin('c.serviceProvider', 'user')
                    ->leftJoin('c.pricingModel', 'p')
                    ->select('MONTH(c.scheduleAt) AS m','(c.serviceProvider) AS sp')
                    ->where('user.refer_token=:token')
                    ->setParameter('token',$serviceProvider->getToken())
                    ->andwhere('c.status= :s_id')
                    ->setParameter('s_id', 'Finished')
                    ->groupBy('sp')
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();`
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1
> of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
> column 'illicon.c0_.schedule_at' which is not functionally dependent
> on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
> sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: This is not a syntax error, but rather the mode of MySQL.
Currently, the data retrieved has more than one row of different data on selected fields, so MySQL does not know which row group by will choose.
If you want MySQL to be randomized, you can remove only_full_group_by mode (but as recommended by the MySQL homepage, you shouldn't)
You can check the current MySQL mode with the command
SELECT @@sql_mode
and remove all mode with SET sql_mode = '' to test this query again

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, you may also be running into the fact that Doctrine's DQL is not the same as SQL.  Trying to set additional aliases as sp is probably not going to work as expected in DQL.